# Redirect loop (only on online server but not on localhost)

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, infinite-loop

I made a site in php, sql, html and CSS. When I ran this site on my localhost everything worked perfectly fine. But when I uploaded it (and automatically added a .htaccess file) to an online server, it gave me a redirection loop error. 
The redirection structure of my page is the following:

**index.php:**

-form one with "button" tags (not input type: button) --> post method: page1.php

-form two with "button" tags (not input type: button) --> post method: page2.php

-form three with "button" tags (not input type: button) --> post method: page3.php

**page1.php:**

-php/sql processing (inserting variables in database, calculating them, ...)

-header(location: index.php)(that is automatically executed after the other php code)

**page2.php:**

-php/sql processing (inserting variables in database, calculating them, ...)

-header(location: index.php)(that is automatically executed after the other php code)

**page3.php:**

-instant run of a header(location: index.php);

to reload the page

All help is appreciated,

Bibbox3

Comment: can we see your .htaccess file ?

Comment: there's nothing in it, only "# Do not remove this line or mod_rewrite rules and search engine friendly URLs will stop working
RewriteBase /" so it's probably a mistake in my index.php file, i'll post it online

Comment: here's my index.php file http://www.4shared.com/file/zs71QmTH/index.html

Comment: Great !!  You should add the answer and accept it.

Comment: What was your solution?

Comment: -1 for not posting the solution